# how can i select element from the dropdown menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Here i am creating a common method in class Common.java for selecting elements based on `visibleText`.And in another class(**NewTest.java**) I am calling the value of `sellectByVisibleText`. But when I am debugging this program it shows 
    error found :

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException:

Element should have been "**select**" but was "**input**". so how can I select employee from dropdown list??

1) Common.java

```
    public static String selectByVisibletext(String xPath,String inputData, WebDriver driver) {
                WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
                try {
                    System.out.println(inputData);
                    System.out.println(xPath);
                    System.out.println(driver);
                    Select selectBox = new Select(webElement);
                    selectBox.selectByVisibleText(inputData);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("error found : "+e);
                }
                return inputData;
            }
```

1) NewTest.java

```
    String search = "//input[@class='select2-search__field']";

     public void employee() {
    Common.selectByVisibletext(search,"Employee", driver);
    }
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: this is java code sir, no html coded are included

Comment: Please provide HTML source of page You're trying to automte to get to see if selectors are ok? tnx

Comment: <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-acc_roles-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-acc_roles-container" title="--- Please select access role---">--- Please select access role---</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that if the tag is not a "select" tag :

```
public static String selectByVisibletext(String xPath,String inputData, WebDriver driver) {
        WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
        try {
            System.out.println(inputData);
            System.out.println(xPath);
            System.out.println(driver);
            Select selectBox = new Select(webElement);
            selectBox.selectByVisibleText(inputData);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
           if (e.getMessage().contains("UnexpectedTagNameException")) {
               List<WebElement> dropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
               dropDown.forEach(dropElement -> {
                   if (dropElement.getAttribute("innerText").equals(inputData)) {
                       dropElement.click();
                   }
               });
           }
        }
        return inputData;
    }
```

The concept is to collect the elements using your selector in a List and then find a match for your desired selectable element and then click on it.

First click on "//input[@class='select2-search__field']" and then find a selector for all dropdown elements and then get them as a list of WebElements and select by matching your text.

Comment: Why would You do any searching in catch part. Is in it than wrong by design? And have to think about some other solutions. My opinion is that is wrong to do any actions, to look further for elements in catch part. So if there is exception, You handle it by locate more elements in list? I think it is a bad design? I'am certain there is much better solution, if HTML is provided.

Comment: @Kovacic OfCourse it is bad by design. I was just trying to update the existing code and thats all only.

Answer (score 0):

The Select class only works with SELECT tags that have option fields. If there are no option fields they would be rejected. If you can post the HTML that would be great. And also you are passing the string holding an INPUT tag into your method. You should pass in an XPATH which actually holds a SELECT tag.

Clearly the below(which you are passing into the method) is a XPATH to an Input field and not a Select field:

```
String search = "//input[@class='select2-search__field']";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the drop down is not made of **select options HTML tags** , then Selenium select class will not work.

In that case, you will have to store all **options** in a **list**. Then you can Iterate through the list and put one condition. Something like.

First click on drop down.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-acc_roles-container")).click();
```

Then store every options in a list like this :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath for all option. This xpath should contain every options"));
      for(WebElement option : options) {
          if(option.getText().trim().contains("What you want to select from drop down")) {
              option.click();
          }  
      }
```

Hope this will help.